# Shore durometer type D to brinells

Tags: materials, material-science

I saw a video where a person was measuring hardness of a material with Shore durometer type D and was comparing it to steel. The screen on durometer showed 96.5 HD and I was just wondering, how much would that be in Brinells? (or alternatively Rockwellss or Vickers)

Comment: http://www.carbidedepot.com/formulas-hardness.htm

Comment: I doubt you can find a conversion. You may be able to develop your own comparison for the material you have. The test loads are very different : Shore D uses 5 Kg, Rockwell A uses 60 Kg + 10 Kg, Brinell uses 500 Kg or 3000 Kg. Also the penetrators are different ; Rockwell uses a diamond cone, Brinell uses a carbide ball.  You are sort of looking for "how many apples equals an orange'